# How to reference an equation without knowing the number for it?

Tags: cross-referencing, equations

I have done this with figures before using.

```
\ref{}
```

Where you give the image an associated name so that it does not matter whether you change up the order, (i.e. latex will automatically number your referenced figure correctly).

I am sure it is possible for equations but I have not been able to find out how to do it. This would be very handy to be able to achieve as I am often dealing with lots and lots of equations and moving them about.

Here is a snippet of what I have been writing for my equations:

```
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
E_{k}={m  {\langle v^2 \rangle} \over 2 } = \frac{3k_{B}T}{2}
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

I tried messing about with other ways but could not find the right way to use `\ref{}` or similar to get the desired result! Can anyone advise?

Comment: May I ask why you put a split into an align? Is that a strongly simplified example or do you actually use it like that?

Comment: This works by default. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that shows what you're looking at that is problematic. Code snippets doesn't provide a wide enough scope for what you mentioned "doesn't work."

Comment: You have to insert `\label{id}` in the equation, and then use `\ref{id}` (where `id` is the identifier of the equation) to refer to it.

Comment: @max I have been using it but I am not quite sure the meaning to be honest.I am just about to try '\label' now...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This MWE show references to equations with `\ref`, `\eqref`and some other alternative commands, as well as page references:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

The equation \ref{a} on page \pageref{a} 
showed a simple $a$ 
formula with simple references. 
The next equation \eqref{Ek} is more complicated, 
as the reference, that need the package \texttt{amsmath}. 
For intelligent references see the commands for these
references to \cref{Ek} \vpageref{Ek} using
\texttt{cleveref} and \texttt{varioref} packages. 
You can also hyperlik \hyperref[Ek]{this equation} 
with \texttt{hyperref} as well as most previous references. 
There are more packages for references, but don't use all 
at once (even only these in the wrong order are a source 
of problems).

\begin{equation} 
\label{a} a = b + c
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{Ek} E_{k}={m {\langle v^2 \rangle} \over 2 }%
= \frac{3k_{B}T}{2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: if `amsmath` is used, the command `\eqref{...}` places the reference in parentheses, and is always upright even in an italic environment (such as `theorem`).

Comment: @barbarabeeton, Good point, I updated the example with \eqref and some others referencing methods.

Comment: I know some wouldn't worry about this but I wouldnt start a sentence with `(2)` followed by a lowercase letter. I'd always rephrase the sentence. _Equation 2,_ _In (2),_ etc.